# Is there a way to detect fake domain name of email address? Using Perl, php, javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, perl, email

If anyone knows how can we detect fake domain names of email addresses, it would be a great help.

Note, that I don't want to validate an email. I want to know if the email domain name exists or not.

Comment: So something like an NSLOOKUP isn't possible? or http://php.net/gethostbyaddr

Comment: The domain could exist but the email address itself couldn't.. what's the use of only checking the domain?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=whois+api&rlz=1C1GGGE_ruUA538UA538&oq=whois+api&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4059j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @AliTrixx, you are right, but at least if i can detect the domain if fake or not, I can avoid much spam users.

Answer (score 2):

in php there is a function `checkdnsrr`

[How do you check if a domain name exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460816/how-do-you-check-if-a-domain-name-exists)

```
if (checkdnsrr('test.nl', 'A')) // or use ANY or for other see above link
{
    echo 'Domain exists';
}
else 
{ 
    echo 'Domain does not exist'; 
}
```

------------------ Code that is working -------

```
 <?php 

if (checkdnsrr('google.com', 'A')) // or use ANY or for other see above link
{
    echo 'Domain exists';
}
else 
{ 
    echo 'Domain does not exist'; 
}

?>
//Output = Domain exists
```

//

```
if (checkdnsrr('fakewebtesting.com', 'A')) // or use ANY or for other see above link
{
    echo 'Domain exists';
}
else 
{ 
    echo 'Domain does not exist'; 
}

?>
  //Output = Domain does not exists
```

I hope you are extracting domain name from email and using it in this function.

Docs link:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php

Comment: Whatever I'm trying it says domain exists. It does not seem to help me.

Comment: I tried and it give me exact. can you please post some code you are using

Comment: I tried your sample. It gave me exactly this: Domain existsDomain exists

Comment: working for me again here. Can you please post you code here i can test it.

Comment: which version of PHP are you using? and on Windows or Linux because change log says that : 5.3.0  This function is now available on Windows platforms.

Comment: try this code as well. getmxrr ('yahoo.com', $out);
print_r($out);

$a = checkdnsrr('yahoo.com', 'MX');
var_dump($a);

Comment: or check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195396/checkdnsrr-returns-wrong-info